# Mouse button press understand control that loses focus (wpf - C#)

Tags: c#, controls, mouse, lost-focus

Good afternoon
in a project I have to intercept the shift of focus from one textbox to another any control present in the window when the left mouse button is pressed.

The problem is that once the key has been pressed I detect the receiving control while I would need to know the source control in order to be able to carry out checks on the data present and, in the event of an error, refocus on the source control.

At this moment I already have an event connected with the LOSTFOCUS on the source control but when I try to change the focus (once the data error is detected) to the offending TextBox this is not minimally detected and the focus goes to the new selected control.

I have been surfing the net since yesterday but I can't find anything that solves the problem.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can fix the problem.

Thanks and good job

Perini Luca